# How to have PostGIS 2.1 and the Python osgeo library installed together without compiling from source?

Tags: python, gdal, postgis-2.0, osgeo

My python application makes heavy use of the `osgeo` library. We're looking to upgrade from PostGIS 1.5 to PostGIS 2.1, and I'm having issues.

I'm installing packages from the Ubuntu GIS PPA.

Before, I would install the `python-gdal` Ubuntu package to install GDAL with a copy of the `osgeo` python library. I would also install `postgresql-9.1-postgis`.  Now, installing `postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1` uninstalls `python-gdal`, and vice versa. They are incompatible with one another, since one requires `libgdal1` and the other requires `libgdal1h`. I have found instructions to compile `libgdal` from source, specifying to include the `osgeo` python library, but I would prefer to use a package if possible.

Does anyone know of a way to have PostGIS 2.1 and the Python `osgeo` library installed together without having to compile from source?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 precise

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I have the exact answer, but I fought with this one trying to get newer versions of PostGIS, GDAL, and MapServer working on on an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server, and had identical problems with packages getting un-installed.  My preference was also to stick with standard packages.  The sequence that I followed to get things working is outlined here:

[PostGIS Raster in MapServer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87721/postgis-raster-in-mapserver/87829#87829)

And more specifically from build notes:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gdal-bin
sudo apt-get install libgdal1
sudo apt-get install libgdal1-dev
gdal-config --version

sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'
wget --quiet -O - http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install Postgresql-9.3-postgis postgresql-contrib

sudo apt-get install cgi-mapserver
sudo apt-get install mapserver-bin
/usr/lib/cgi-bin/mapserv -v
```

This was a useful reference: http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS21UbuntuPGSQL93Apt

Hope this helps, Brian.